# bind two arrays with x and y datapoints to a line chart in asp.net?

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-charts

Does anyone know how to bind two arrays (x and y datapoints) to form a line chart using the asp.net chart toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to for loop the datapoints and use:

Chart.Series["ChartName"].Points.AddXY(x[i], y[i])

Comment: Hi , I'm having a similar issue - would you still have your sample code that i could have a look? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the arrays with:

```
my_series.Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
```